# scroll view doesnt zooming and horizontal scrolling together?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, zooming

I'm newbie at iOS programming. I want to do zooming and horizontal scrolling. When the page did load, I can't scrolling up to pinch. when I pinch, then I'm able to scroll. What's the reason of this?

Here's my code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollview.delegate = self
    //mark:- for scrolling
    let scrollViewFrame = scrollview.frame
    let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / scrollview.contentSize.width
    let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / scrollview.contentSize.height
    let minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    scrollview.minimumZoomScale = minScale;

    scrollview.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
    scrollview.zoomScale = 0.8


}
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    statsView.drawStatsView(color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.6862745285, blue: 0.1333333403, alpha: 1), average: 100, min: 90, max: 110, name: "H")
    statsView.drawStatsView(color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.7450980544, green: 0.1568627506, blue: 0.07450980693, alpha: 1), average: 120, min: 102, max: 122, name: "A")
    statsView.drawStatsView(color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.2392156869, green: 0.6745098233, blue: 0.9686274529, alpha: 1), average: 145, min: 130, max: 150, name: "Y")
}
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   // bunu bi düşün containera statsView.Container.addConstraint()
    scrollview.contentSize = CGSize(width: 720, height: scrollview.frame.height)
    scrollview.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
    scrollview.bounces = false
    scrollview.clipsToBounds = true

}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    print("we re zooming yey")
    return statsView
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53688709/creating-zoom-on-uiimageview-in-swift/53695515#53695515 , you will get some idea from this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three steps:

1. First: Make sure your scroll view has a maximum zoom scale larger
   than the default of 1.0. You can change this in Interface Builder if
   you want, or use the `maximumZoomScale` property in code.
2. Make your view controller the `delegate` of your scroll view.
3. Make your view controller conform to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol, then add the `viewForZooming(in:)`

   ```
   func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? { 
   return imageView
   }
   ```

Comment: Check out this tutorial for an extensive explanation to zoom on UIScrollview: https://www.appcoda.com/uiscrollview-introduction/